# Starting a singleTask activity causes it to spawn on top of the caller task

Tags: android

I have an activity that has singleTask launch mode. This activity can receive shared content from other apps, using these filters:

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
            </intent-filter>
```

When I share an URL from Google Chrome for instance, my activity is created correctly, but instead of getting created on its own task, is created on top of the Chrome task. Isn't the singleTask launch mode meant to prevent this? Both my activity and my application has affinity explicitly defined on the manifest. Is there something else needed in this case?

Manifest:

```
    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:taskAffinity="my.example.app"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode|layoutDirection|locale"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:taskAffinity="my.example.app"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could figure out was to create a new activity for the sole purpose of handling ACTION_SEND intents and pass them to the main activity. This new activity should have an entire blank UI.